# Use external array from another file in static class

Tags: php

I'm currently working on a project where I have to work with huge arrays. With huge, I mean 1k elements or more. Since these are a lot of arrays and i sometimes mess things up, I decided to create a class with static functions so i can call the functions which would make the entire project easier to read. This is what I currently have:

ArrayAccess.class.php:

```
require "dep/arrays/elements.php";
class ArrayAccess {

    public static function get_value_from_element($element) {
        return $elements[$element];
    }
}
```

elements.php:

```
<?php
$elements = array(
    "sam" => 6, ... and so on ...
```

I simply want to be able to use `ArrayAccess::get_value_from_element($element)` in my project. It is so much easier to read than all these indexes everywhere. However, the array is defined in the `elements.php` file - I can't use that in the class.

So how can I access the array in my class? Please note, I cannot copy it into the class, the file would be larger than 400k lines, this is not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `return` a value from an include (or require in this case) and store that to a static property the first time the function is called.

elements.php:

```
<?php
return array("sam" => 6, ...);
```

DataAccess.php:

```
class DataAccess {

    private static $elements = array();

    public static function get_value_from_element($element) {
        if(self::$elements === array()) {
            self::$elements = require "elements.php";
        }
        return self::$elements[$element];
    }
}
```

You should also avoid naming your class `ArrayAccess`, since it already [exists](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) in PHP.

Comment: Small, clean and does its job perfectly, exactly what i was looking for. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

In `elements.php`

```
<?php
return array( // use return so you can retrieve these into a variable
      "sam" => 6, ... and so on ...
```

Then in the class

```
<?php
class ArrayAccess {
    public static $elements = null; // set up a static var to avoid load this big array multiple times
    public static function get_value_from_element($element) {
        if(self::$elements === null) { // check if null to load it from the file
            self::$elements = require('elements.php');
        }
        return self::$elements[$element]; // there you go
    }
}
```

If you don't want do the `if` statement in the getter every time, you should probably find some where else to load the file into the static variable before using the getter.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to declare $elements as global in your class:

```
require "dep/arrays/elements.php";
class ArrayAccess {

    public static function get_value_from_element($element) {
        global $elements;
        return $elements[$element];
    }
}
```